# What do these columns stand for?

Tags: linux

Just started to dabble in linux.  Other than the date can someone tell me what each column is?  Overview wise.  I got to this point by cd /home   ls =la

```
drwxr-xr-x  9 root         root         4096 Aug 27 22:02 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 root         root         4096 Oct  3 14:48 ..
drwxr-xr-x  4 admispconfig admispconfig 4096 Dec  7  2010 admispconfig
drwxr-xr-x  2 jsmith       root         4096 Oct 15  2008 jsmith
```

If I were to guess the 3rd is the user, the 4th is the level of user, and the 6th is date/time created. But I'm not sure about the rest.

I will be going through a few beginning tutorials this weekend and if all goes well I'll sign up for a intro class at the local college. So I'm testing the waters so to speak.

Comment: permissions, links, uid, gid, size, date, name. It's all in `man ls`.

Comment: First column is read/write permissions per user/group

Comment: I'm OK with down votes. I'm not OK with down votes with no explanation.  How can I correct what is wrong with out knowing what you were thinking.

Comment: This question is not directly programming related. If you've got more of such questions, you should also checkout http://unix.stackexchange.com/ - also please pose new questions only after the consultation of documentation resources (e.g. manpage `man man`) and a short research on the web.

Comment: In the tooltab for the downvote button there is the statement: _"This question does not show any research effort; ..."_. And probably, this will also be the reason for the downvote in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [`man ls`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ls):

> **The Long Format**
>
> If the `-l` option is given, the following information is displayed for
>        each file: file mode, number of links, owner name, group name, number of
>        bytes in the file, abbreviated month, day-of-month file was last modified, hour file last modified, minute file last modified, and the pathname.  In addition, for each directory whose contents are displayed, the
>        total number of 512-byte blocks used by the files in the directory is
>        displayed on a line by itself, immediately before the information for the
>        files in the directory.  If the file or directory has extended
>        attributes, the permissions field printed by the `-l` option is followed by
>        a '@' character.  Otherwise, if the file or directory has extended security information (such as an access control list), the permissions field
>        printed by the `-l` option is followed by a '+' character.
>
> If the modification time of the file is more than 6 months in the past or
>        future, then the year of the last modification is displayed in place of
>        the hour and minute fields.
>
> If the owner or group names are not a known user or group name, or the `-n`
>        option is given, the numeric ID's are displayed.
>
> If the file is a character special or block special file, the major and
>        minor device numbers for the file are displayed in the size field.  If
>        the file is a symbolic link, the pathname of the linked-to file is preceded by ``->''.

I'm not going to quote the whole thing here. `man ls` is *remarkably* detailed about the meaning of the permissions column.